# Android WebView but no other components

Tags: android, xml, webview

Looking for a web to have `webview` along side buttons and `Textviews`. When running below code the `webview` is the only thing available on that `Activity`.

```
public class Tab2Activity extends Activity
{
    private WebView xWebview ;



    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.tab2);


        ///////////////////////////////////////////////

        TextView tvVenue = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.venue);
        TextView tvAddress = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.address);
        TextView tvCity = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.city);
        TextView tvPostCode = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.postcode);
        TextView tvDate = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.Vdate);
        TextView tvTime = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.Vtime);




        Button fest = (Button)findViewById(R.id.veganfestival);
        Button nav = (Button)findViewById(R.id.nav);
        Button buyTicket = (Button)findViewById(R.id.buyticket);

        fest.setText(MainActivity.whichFest);

        if (MainActivity.whichFest.equals("Aberdeen"))
        {
            tvVenue.setText("Aberdeen Football Club");
            tvAddress.setText("Pittodrie Street");
            tvCity.setText("Aberdeen");
            tvPostCode.setText("AB24 5QH");
            tvDate.setText("Saturday 28th May 2017");
            tvTime.setText("10:30am - 4pm");
            venueLocation="Aberdeen Football Club";

        }
        //////////////////////////////////////////////
        if (MainActivity.whichFest.equals("Newcastle"))
        {
            tvVenue.setText("The Assembly Rooms");
            tvAddress.setText("Fenkle Street");


        xWebview = new WebView(this);

        xWebview.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true); // enable javascript


        xWebview.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient());
        xWebview.clearCache(true);
        xWebview.getSettings().setUserAgentString("Android WebView");
        xWebview.loadUrl(MainActivity.MapLocation);
        setContentView(xWebview);
}
```

**This is XML**

```
<ScrollView 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:background="#332b2b"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearlayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"

        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/veganfestival"

            android:text="Aberdeen"
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
            android:textSize="30sp"

            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="60dp"
            android:background="@drawable/buttonshape"
            android:shadowColor="#A8A8A8"
            android:shadowDx="0"
            android:shadowDy="0"
            android:shadowRadius="5"

            />
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/blank"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"

            android:textSize="20dp"
            android:textColor="#ffffff" />
        <View
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="1dp"
            android:background="#6f844a" />
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/venue"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Venue"
            android:textSize="20dp"
            android:textColor="#ffffff" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/address"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Address"
            android:textSize="20dp"
            android:textColor="#ffffff" />
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/city"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="City"
            android:textSize="20dp"
            android:textColor="#ffffff" />
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/postcode"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Postcode"
            android:textSize="20dp"
            android:textColor="#ffffff" />
        <View
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="1dp"
            android:background="#6f844a" />
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/Vdate"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Date"
            android:textSize="20dp"
            android:textColor="#ffffff" />
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/Vtime"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Time"
            android:textSize="20dp"
            android:textColor="#ffffff" />
        <View
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="1dp"
            android:background="#6f844a" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/blankagain"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"

            android:textSize="20dp"
            android:textColor="#ffffff" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/buyticket"

            android:text="Buy Ticket"
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
            android:textSize="30sp"

            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="60dp"
            android:background="@drawable/buttonshape"
            android:shadowColor="#A8A8A8"
            android:shadowDx="0"
            android:shadowDy="0"
            android:shadowRadius="5"

            />
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/blankmore"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"

            android:textSize="20dp"
            android:textColor="#ffffff" />

        <WebView
            android:id="@+id/webviewb"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/nav"

            android:text="Take Me There"
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
            android:textSize="30sp"

            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="60dp"
            android:background="@drawable/buttonshape"
            android:shadowColor="#A8A8A8"
            android:shadowDx="0"
            android:shadowDy="0"
            android:shadowRadius="5"

            />


    </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>
```

If anyone has a work around or some advice on how to achieve this - it would be much appreciated.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [android webview layout to take remaining space](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10147803/android-webview-layout-to-take-remaining-space)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is obviously related to the XML, as the webview is taking all the available space.

Take into consideration the following:

- WebView has a width and height of "fill_parent", this means it will have *exactly* the same height as the LinearLayout it is wrapped in.
- Your TextViews and Buttons are also contained in the same LinearLayout, not allowing them to be visible, as the webview is taking all the space.

I would advice moving the webview into a different layout (it can be a Linear or Relative one). Depending on the needs of your view, you can define the space used by your textviews and buttons using weights, dps, or just by wrapping content.

If you want the webview to use all the "remaining space" you can use a LinearLayout, and give your WebView in this case a weight of 1. Something like this:

```
<LinearLayout 
      android:layout_width="fill_parent"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:orientation="horizontal"
      >

     <Button
        android:layout_width = "match_parent"
        android:layout_weight = "0"
        android:layout_height = "wrap_content"
        android:text="text!"/>
     <WebView
        android:layout_width = "fill_parent"
        android:layout_height = "wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight = "1"/>
     <Button
        android:layout_width = "80dp"
        android:layout_weight = "0"
        android:layout_height = "wrap_content"
        android:text="text!"/>   
 </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Thanks. Are you saying have to layouts on same activity. I also reduced size of webview and made no difference.

Comment: @MarkJames Instead of using height of "fill_parent" on your WebView, use the code I provided. Giving your WebView a weight of 1, while using a height of wrap_content will automatically take the remaining space.

Comment: Try copying and pasting the exact same code; your layout height should be set to "wrap_content", and other elements should have a weight of 0.